# Modify detail view while master view displays

Tags: ios, ipad, master-detail

I'm building a splitviewcontroller-based app for the iPad in portrait mode. When the master view displays it overlays the detail view, partially hiding it. In my app the user can delete items listed in the master view. If the user deletes the master item associated with the data currently displayed in the detail view I would like to change the detail view (ie clear it or display details for the next item). However, pushing or popping views on the detail navigation controller while the master view is showing causes the master view to slide offscreen.

Is there a way I can modify the detail view without causing the master view to hide? I would like to allow the user to continue working with the master view regardless of what happens to the detail view.

Thanks

Comment: Is the master view a view controller that is modally presented from the detail view controller?

Comment: I'm not sure. Both the  master and detail views are presented by the splitviewcontroller. The master view does not cover the entire screen so I don't know if it is considered a modal presentation.